How to fetch secret from multiple Spring cloud vault in spring boot application
We are trying to use spring cloud vault to keep database credentials by using spring boot application. We are having multiple database related properties in application.properties file. We need to store/fetch database credentials from different spring cloud vault. Is it possible to create different vault for different database credentials. Please suggest.

Can any one help here?
